# how to capture message shown in alert box

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Here i need to get message that is displayed on alert box and click ok using javascript.

for example : alert("hello");

above that code displays message as hello which is coming from an other website I need to capture that message using javascript and script to get message and hit button.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish (it is a bit unclear)? Are you saying that you want your code to pretend to be a user of a website (which you have not built) and read an alert-box and give a reply? If that is the case, then that might be unethical.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way:

```
function captureAlert() {
  // get all scripts
  var elem = document.scripts;

  // loop and check
  for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

    var txt = elem[i].textContent.match(/alert\(['"]([^'"]+)['"]\)/);
    if (txt) { return txt[1]; } // if matched, return the alert value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just overwrite ***alert*** function.

```js
var fn = alert;
alert = function(text) {
    document.write('<b>'+text+'</b>')
  alert = fn;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('hello123')">Click</button>
```